# How to send e-mail alert when SQL Server data row equals to specified value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, email, c#-4.0

Here i have a sql server data table with date type of column. I want to send an e-mail alert to specified e-mail address when the difference of the stored date and the current date less than five. How can i do this?I'm doing this with ASP.NET and behind code is C#.Please explain me how to do this.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using? It sounds like a job for SQL Server Agent.

Comment: *Edition*? - Express, Standard, Enterprise...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to create a windows service and make it run after every x minutes.In this windows service you just need to check your required condition and if its true just send email else be idle.

Or else

you can also achieve this by using triggers but thats only fires when there is any insert/update on the table and matched your condition.This will not keep checking always but only when there is any action on the table.

Comment: could you please explain more about the first way.

Comment: There is something called Windows service which will run in the background and keep monitoring your table.This can be done in C#.net.Its just a normal C#.net code.The only difference is you have to choose console application when you create a new project in C#.net

Comment: Read more about Windows Service - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample